# What is the radius of a circle in a corner of a rectangle which is touching the two sides of the rectangle and an inscribed elipse?

Tags: calculus

Find the radius of the circle in terms of dimension of rectangle ?[image]

I tried to solve using co-ordinate geometry, slope of tangent, slope of normal. But could not get a solution. If the problem is square and circle it is easy to solve. But for an ellipse and rectangle, the solution becomes complicated. But I am looking for an elegant formula for the radius of circle in-terms of semi major and minor axis of the ellipse.Please help solve the problem

Comment: I tried to solve using co-ordinate geometry, slope of tangent, slope of normal. But could not get a solution. If the problem is square and circle it is easy to solve. But for an ellipse and rectangle, the solution becomes complicated. But I am looking for an elegant formula for the radius of circle in-terms of semi major and minor axis of the ellipse.Please help solve the problem

Comment: You would do well to show some of your attempts at solving this. Perhaps you’re on the right track already and just need a small hint to get to the solution.

Comment: Thanks. I added new comment. Please respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Suppose that the sides of rectangle are $2a$ and $2b$. Radius of the circle is denoted with $r$. Touch point $T$ has coordinates $(p,q)$ and they must satisfy the equation of the ellipse:

$$\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{q^2}{b^2}=1\tag{1}$$

Also, $CT=r$, which translates to:

$$(a-r-p)^2+(b-r-q)^2=r^2\tag{2}$$

The equaiton of the ellipse is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

which means that:

$$\frac{x}{a^2}+\frac{yy'}{b^2}=0$$

So the slope of the tangent to the ellipse at any given point is:

$$y'=-\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$$

...or, at point $T$:

$$y_T'=-\frac{b^2p}{a^2q}$$

Line $CT$ is perpendicular to tangent so the slope of line CT must be $-1/y_T'$. It means that:

$$\frac{b-r-q}{a-r-p}=\frac{a^2q}{b^2p}$$

$$b^2p(b-r-q)=a^2q(a-r-p)\tag{3}$$

Equations (1), (2) and (3) have three unknowns: $p,q,r$.

From this point on you have two choices:

- Try to solve these equations by hand and die along the way.
- Use Mathematica and save a big part of your life for something more entertaining.

There are two trivial solutions, circles with center at $(0,0)$ and radii $a$ and $b$. There are four more solutions, because you can put your small circle in four different corners of the rectangle. Here is the solution for the top-right one:

$$p=\frac{a^{3/2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$$

$$q=\frac{b^{3/2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$$

$$r=(a+b+\sqrt{ab})-\frac{a \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a} b+a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$$

If $a=b$ the solution is:

$$p=q=\frac{a\sqrt2}2$$

$$r=a(3-2\sqrt2)$$

Comment: Wonderful. My new attempt to solve this problem, I considered an ellipse going around the original ellipse at a constant distance of radius of the circle. I assumed the equation of this new ellipse as

Comment: x^2/(a+r)^2+y^2/(b+r)^2=1 .I then substituted the point (a-r, b-r) to lie on the above ellipse. I solved for r graphically.  But the results are not correct. I do not know where I have gone wrong? Please help

Comment: @K.Subramanian Are you sure that the locus of the center of the rolling circle is also an ellipse? That curve certainly looks like ellipse but you need a hard proof that it really is. It's an interesting question that you can post here separately. BTW, if you consider my answer correct, I would appreciate if you accepted it! Thanks.

Comment: I am revisiting this problem after a long gap. Can you help me with the note book creation in Mathematica to solve the the three equations. I am new to Mathematica. I have Mathematica version 13.01 in my computer.